# Problems with OAuth regarding jetty

Tags: java, android, oauth, jetty, oauth-2.0

I've got following problem:

When trying to get credentials through OAuth2, I got the runtime Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mortbay.jetty.Server
                                               at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
                                               at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
```

When now trying to import jetty through dependencies and excluding it in other packages, I get following gradle error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK org/mortbay/jetty/build/resources/javadoc.css
>       File1: C:\Users\Bene.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mortbay.jetty\jetty\7.0.0.pre5\e32f430450dffb9c44e525ad7c86aa6efd3a9983\jetty-7.0.0.pre5.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Bene.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mortbay.jetty\jetty-util\7.0.0.pre5\d05f4eb4c5e751ae1ce325b58eed8a51c51f216e\jetty-util-7.0.0.pre5.jar

which somehow looks like there is a duplicate file in the jetty package itself.

I'll now copy my dependencies and the code, that is afflicted:

```
dependencies {
// compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
//    compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-android2:1.4.1-beta'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v2-rev109-1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
//    compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-auth-oauth2:1.2.3-alpha'
compile('com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty'
}
compile('com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.api.client.auth.oauth'
    exclude group: 'org.mortbay.jetty'
    exclude module: 'json'
}
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.12.0-beta'
compile('org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:7.0.0.pre5')
```

"new LocalServerReceiver" seems to throw that Exception

```
credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!